# How to ungroup vertices?

Tags: vertices, selection-tools, vertex-groups

When i use box select on one vertice, Blender somehow selects some others. Vertex groups list of this object is empty.
So, the question is what's going on and how to avoid it?
[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]

Comment: How are vertex groups related to Bounding Box selection tool?

Answer (score 1):

Is this the in UV Image Editor? If is try disabling *Sticky Selection* in the *Image Editor* header bar
That will force automatic selection of vertex sharing the same UV coordinate.

[image]